# codingbat Problem: close_far | failing only one test | heeeelp

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

**Exercise:**
Given three ints, a b c, return True if one of b or c is "close" (differing from a by at most 1), while the other is "far", differing from both other values by 2 or more. Note: abs(num) computes the absolute value of a number.

https://codingbat.com/prob/p160533

**My code:**

```
def close_far(a, b, c):
  if (b == a + 1 or a - 1 or a) or (c == a + 1 or a - 1 or a):        #looking for the "close" one
    if (c > a + 2 and b + 2) or (c <= a - 2 and b - 2):               #looking for c to be the "far" one
        return True
    elif (b > (a + 2 and c + 2)) or (b <= (a - 2 and c - 2)):         #looking for b to be the "far" one
        return True
    else:    
      return False
```

The wrong answer for -> close_far(4, 3, 5) → False  True    X

My code gives out True despite its False.

---

I actually don't know what i'm doing wrong there. I guess there is something wrong with my 2nd if-statement... parentheses? or/and ?
appreciate any help!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNHQC.png)

Comment: [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i got it right! I messed up the parentheses in the elif statement causing the test to fail. You got me on the right track Johnny Mopp, thanks for the help.

```
def close_far(a, b, c):
  if (b == a + 1 or a - 1 or a) or (c == a + 1 or a - 1 or a):              #looking for the "close" one
    if ((c > a + 2) and (c > b + 2)) or ((c <= a - 2) and (c <= b - 2)):    #looking for c to be the "far" one
        return True
    elif (b > (a + 2 and c + 2)) or ((b <= a - 2) and (b <= c - 2)):        #looking for b to be the "far" one
        return True
    else:    
      return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried the simple OR , AND operations. Worked for me fine.

```
def close_far(a, b, c):
  if abs(b-c)>=2:
    if (abs(a-b)<=1 and abs(a-c)>=2) or ( abs(a-c)<=1 and abs(a-b)>=2):
      return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def close_far(a, b, c):

  close_b = close(b, a) 
  close_c = close(c, a)

  far_b = far(b, a) and far(b, c)
  far_c = far(c, a) and far(c, b)
  
  return close_b and far_c or close_c and far_b
  
  
  
def close(a, b):
  
  if (abs(a-b)) < 2:
    return True
  else:
    return False

def far(a, b):
  
  if (abs(a - b)) > 1:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

I found it easier to break down complicated logic structures into separate functions. First creating the close and far functions then validating the output scenarios.

The close function checks given two inputs if they differ by "at most one". The far function checks given two inputs if they differ by "two or more".

Finally validate the cases described by the problem:

1. If 'b' is close to 'a', check that 'c' is far from both 'a' and 'b'.
2. If 'c' is close to 'a', check that 'b' is far from both 'a' and 'c'.